# Have+ object +bare infinitive usage

Tags: infinitives, causative-have

> I will have him believe it

What does this mean? Does this mean “I will make him believe it”?

My friends are saying **have + object** form is used in the sense of **wish**. Is it correct?

Comment: In your example, "have" is called a verb of causation, so your first suggestion is about right. As you say, "make" could substitute for "have" with little effect on the meaning (roughly "force" or "compel").

Comment: I would suggest that this is archaic - not seen anything like this in modern usage.

Comment: I would have him believe it means I want him to, not that I will force him to. I will have him believe it expresses some determination.

Comment: You could easily find the answer to this question by looking in a good dictionary, which will list several possible meanings for **have**, for example RECEIVE/ALLOW and MAKE HAPPEN. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have

Comment: I will have him believing it. =cause him to believe it

Answer (score -1):

Your friends are wrong, but not because of the use of **have + object** specifically.

The distinction comes from the first verb in the sentence:

1. I ***will*** **have** him believe it.
   → I will ***make*** him believe it.
2. I ***would*** **have** him believe it.
    → I ***wish*** he would believe it.    *or*
   → I ***consent to*** him believing it.

It's not only the use of **have + object** that determines the meaning, but its use in combination with the particular tense of the auxiliary verb being used.

Note that the second sentence can have more than one interpretation.

---

If you look at the Merriam-Webster definition of [*will*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will) (which includes its past tense) in its use as an auxiliary verb, you'll see that it's quite complex.

In the first sentence, it uses the "used to express futurity" sense. In the second sentence, it uses the "used to express desire, choice, willingness, consent, or in negative constructions refusal" sense.